# How to show selected columns without Index in Python without using Print statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to find the display the top 10 companies from the list of 2000 based on a particular column. but the issue is when I input the variable to display the data set, it shows the index and I wanted to know is this can be done without using Print statement.

My current code is

```
forbes_global = pd.read_csv("Forbes_Global_2000_2019.csv")
profit_assest_company=forbes_global[['Company','Profits as % of Assets']]
profit_assest_company.sort_values(by=['Profits as % of Assets'],ascending=False).head(10)
```

The current output which I am getting is:

[image]

The desired output which I want is:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can try `print(df.head(10).to_string(index=False))`

Comment: Where are you displaying the data? A jupyter notebook or somewhere else?

Comment: @EricTruett I am trying to display in Jupyter notebook itself.

Comment: @ChihebNexus I don't want to do it with print statement, I did find out how to do with print but i wanted to do it without print statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas styling to hide the index in a jupyter notebook

```
(
  profit_assest_company
  .sort_values(by=['Profits as % of Assets'], ascending=False)
  .head(10)
).style.hide_index()
```